# In C# Do I Ever Have to Perform An Explicit Upcast?

Tags: c#, casting, upcasting

Given a class hierarchy with a base class `B` and a subclass `S`:

```
class B { }
class S : B { }
```

I can assign a `S` to an `B` with an implicit conversion:

```
B b = new S();
```

If I wanted to downcast this back to a `S` I would have to do this explicitly:

```
B b = new S();
...
S s = (S)b;
```

Now, my understanding is we can guarantee that there is always assignment compatibility going from `S` to `B`, so we will never have to perform an explicit upcast in the following way:

```
S s = new S();
B b = (B)s; // or
B b2 = s as B;
```

Is this assertion correct, or as the question states Do I Ever Have to Perform An Explicit Upcast?

Comment: If you are intentionally upcasting objects anywhere in your codebase, I guess you'd be breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
class B { }
class S : B { }
class T : B { }
```

and you try to do something like

```
var b = myBool ? new S() : new T();
```

this won't compile unless you explicitly cast either the `S` or the `T` instance (or both) to `B`.

The same goes for anonymous methods; this

```
new bool[0].Select(b => 
    { if (b) { return new S(); } else { return new T(); } });
```

won't compile without casts (or specifying `Select<bool, B>` but this might not be possible, for example if your source is an anonymous type).

Also, if you have

```
class B { public void DoSomething() { } }
class S : B { public new void DoSomething() { } }
```

then

```
S s = new S();
s.DoSomething();       // calls the S version
((B)s).DoSomething();  // calls the B version
```

Comment: I'm not sure about calling the base version with a cast, I thought it might be the case but went to investigate and it [seems it's not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437926/force-calling-the-base-method-from-outside-a-derived-class)

Comment: @JamesB It doesn't work for virtual methods, but it does for methods hidden by `new`.

Comment: Accepted! For sending me on an interesting tagent.

Answer (score 4):

You might do with interfaces, if the class has got an explicit implementation:

```
interface I {
    void Method();
}

class C : I {
    void I.Method() { ... }
}

C c = new C();
c.Method();      // won't compile
((I)c).Method(); // have to cast to I first
```