# Casting to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Trying to understand cast und inheritance. I have these two very simple classes:

```
  class BaseClass
   {
      public virtual void Print()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Base");
      }
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
      public override void Print()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Derived");
      }
    }
```

When I execute the following code it prints "Derived".

```
    var derived = new DerivedClass();

    ((BaseClass)derived).Print();
```

However

```
     bool isBase = derived is BaseClass;
```

returns true. If derived is now of type BaseClass why is the Method Print from BaseClass not called?

Comment: and the best thing is you have [answer on the linked question from Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15140951/961113)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change names of classes to make things clear:

```
class Animal
{
   public virtual void MakeNoise()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!");
   }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
   public override void MakeNoise() // changing behavior inherited from base
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Bark!");
   }
}
```

Now it does not look strange, yes? Derived class IS A base class. Any dog IS AN animal:

```
var dog = new Dog();
bool isBase = dog is Animal;
```

You can treat any dog as an animal, because dog IS AN animal:

```
var animal = (Animal)dog;
```

But its still a dog. So when you'll ask animal to make a noise:

```
animal.MakeNoise();
```

You will hear dog's barking.

Comment: However when i do think so,                                      Dog dog=new Animal();                                           Looks right, but it's not...

Comment: @newbieftw sorry, didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overriding the base class.  You can call the base class from the sub classs this way:

```
public override void Print()
{
   base.Print();
}
```